# Is there a way of listing files for a directory if it contains index.html?

Tags: security

On my server (over which I have little control), directories are listed by default, so for `mysite.com/images` I get:

> **Index of /images**
>
> Parent Directory
>   BirdsAreHere.png
>   CanYouSpot-AdBlank.jpg

etc. Is putting an index.html in that directory enough to prevent people listing the files, or is there still a way of getting at that list? Is it the same for my web root directory (`mysite.com`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting an index.html file should solve that problem. But if you really want to be sure no one gets the directory list just place an .htaccess file in the root of your www directory with this line in it:

```
Options -Indexes
```

That will prevent Apache from listing the files of your directories.

Answer (score 1):

> Is putting an `index.html` in that directory enough to prevent people listing the files, or is there still a way of getting at that list?

To clarify...

- The directory listing is generated by mod_autoindex when `Options +Indexes` is set.
- `index.html` is the default `DirectoryIndex` document. It is when a `DirectoryIndex` document does not exist in the requested directory that mod_autoindex generates a directory listing of that directory (served with a 200 OK response).
- `Options +Indexes` was enabled by default on Apache 2.2. On Apache 2.4 it is not, however, many shared hosts do explicitly enable this in the server config.

There are a couple of edge cases that can allow the directory listing to still be generated:

1. If you *change* the `DirectoryIndex` document(s) (eg. `DirectoryIndex index.php` in `.htaccess` or server config) then `index.html` is no longer a `DirectoryIndex` document, so a directory listing will be generated.
2. If you disable directory slashes (ie. `DirectorySlash Off`) to prevent slashes being appended to physical directories (sometimes preferred for cosmetic reasons) then even if a `DirectoryIndex` document exists in that directory, when you request the directory *without* a trailing slash, a directory listing will be generated. The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) specifically warn about this behaviour.

   So if you set `DirectorySlash Off` then you *must* also disable mod_autoindex directory listings with `Options -Indexes`, if this behaviour is not desirable.

Placing a minimal `index.html` document in a directory to prevent directory listings is really just a messy workaround for when you don't have access to set `Options -Indexes` (as mentioned in the [other answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8534/1243)) for that directory. Not only would you need to place a `index.html` document in every directory, this also returns a 200 OK response which is less than ideal.